# Pool e Transações com PyMongo

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

Estou fazendo uso de MongoDb + PyMongo pela primeira vez, estou procurando informações de como trabalhar com Pool de conexões e Transações com pymongo. Até o momento com a [documentação](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) encontrei o básico:

```
#Acessando
>>> from pymongo import MongoClient
>>> client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
>>> db = client['test-database']

#Inserindo
>>> import datetime
>>> post = {"author": "Mike",
...         "text": "My first blog post!",
...         "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"],
...         "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}

>>> posts = db.posts
>>> post_id = posts.insert_one(post).inserted_id
>>> post_id
ObjectId('...')
```

Mas como trabalhar com Pool de conexões e transações com Pymongo? O MongoDb 4 já possibilita transações multdocumentos, como fazer essas coisas em pymongo? Onde "entra" o commit e rollback como nos bancos relacionais?

Comment: Quando você diz **Poll de conexões**, significa **Change Streams**?

Comment: Na verdade, o termo correto é Pool e não Poll, acabei de corrigir. Pool de conexões eu já encontrei a resposta. O próprio objeto `MongoClient` já tem um pool de conexões, segundo informações encontradas [aqui](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo).
Porém, como trabalhar com transações com **PyMongo** ainda está obscuro pra mim, não encontrei exemplos de como seria uma transação com commit e rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Transações

O suporte a transações é obtido por 3 métodos no objeto `client_session`:

1. `start_transaction(read_concern=None, write_concern=None, read_preference=None)`
2. `commit_transaction()`
3. `abort_transaction()`, que exerce o papel de rollback

Referência: https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/client_session.html

Um exemplo super simples seria:

```
posts = client.db.posts
with client.start_session() as session:
    with session.start_transaction():
        post_id = posts.insert_one(post, session=session).inserted_id
```

A documentação diz que deste modo, você não precisa se preocupar em chamar `commit_transaction()` ou `abort_transaction()`:

> Upon normal completion of with session.start_transaction() block, the
>   transaction automatically calls ClientSession.commit_transaction(). If
>   the block exits with an exception, the transaction automatically calls
>   ClientSession.abort_transaction().

Mais informações sobre transações, você encontra em https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Neste caso, esse seria o exemplo complicado:

```
def run_transaction_with_retry(txn_func, session):
    while True:
        try:
            txn_func(session)  # performs transaction
            break
        except (ConnectionFailure, OperationFailure) as exc:
            # If transient error, retry the whole transaction
            if exc.has_error_label("TransientTransactionError"):
                print("TransientTransactionError, retrying "
                      "transaction ...")
                continue
            else:
                raise

def commit_with_retry(session):
    while True:
        try:
            # Commit uses write concern set at transaction start.
            session.commit_transaction()
            print("Transaction committed.")
            break
        except (ConnectionFailure, OperationFailure) as exc:
            # Can retry commit
            if exc.has_error_label("UnknownTransactionCommitResult"):
                print("UnknownTransactionCommitResult, retrying "
                      "commit operation ...")
                continue
            else:
                print("Error during commit ...")
                raise

# Updates two collections in a transactions

def meu_metodo_que_adiciona_o_post(session):        
    post = {"author": "Mike",
        "text": "My first blog post!",
        "tags": ["mongodb", "python", "pymongo"],
        "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    posts = session.client.db.posts

    with session.start_transaction(
            read_concern=ReadConcern("snapshot"),
            write_concern=WriteConcern(w="majority")):
        post_id = posts.insert_one(post, session=session).inserted_id

        commit_with_retry(session)

# Start a session.
with client.start_session() as session:
    try:
        run_transaction_with_retry(meu_metodo_que_adiciona_o_post, session)
    except Exception as exc:
        # Do something with error.
        raise
```

Em resumo, deste modo, o código trata várias exceções que podem ocorrer, e tenta efetuar a transação novamente, se for possível.

## Sessões

Anteriormente, o objeto `client_session` foi citado, que no MongoDB representa o conceito de *Session* (**sessão** em português).

Atualmente, uma *Session* tem a função de oferecer **consistência causal**(*causal consistency*) e **transações**.

**Consistência causal** é a propriedade de garantir que as ordens das operações acontecem da forma especificada, e que se uma operação A acontece antes da operação B, a operação B receberá todos os efeitos da operação A.

Referência sobre *causal-consistency*: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#causal-consistency

> With causally consistent sessions, MongoDB executes causal operations
>   in an order that respect their causal relationships, and clients
>   observe results that are consistent with the causal relationships.

Dito isto, consistência causal não quer dizer que é o mesmo que transações, e também não garantem isolamento. Ou seja, outras operações de outras conexões podem afetar o conteúdo do que é visto durante as operações dentro da sessão:

> Operations within a causally consistent session are not isolated from
>   operations outside the session. If a concurrent write operation
>   interleaves between the session’s write and read operations, the
>   session’s read operation may return results that reflect a write
>   operation that occurred after the session’s write operation.

Então, o uso indicado de *causally consistent*, é para evitar que o banco de dados tente executar todas as operações ao mesmo tempo, executando elas em sequência.

Por padrão, toda *session* já é *causally consistent*, mas você pode desabilitar se quiser.

**AVISO:** Em relação a **sessões e transações**, use sempre `ReadConcern('majority')` e `WriteConcern('majority')`.

Se não seguir este aviso, o comportamento do banco de dados é [bem mais complicado](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/causal-consistency-read-write-concerns/). É lógico que se você entende o que diferentes *Read\Write Concerns* fazem nas operações, e como afetam as *Replica Sets/Shards*, este aviso deve ser ignorado.

Comment: Então os commits e rollbacks são implícitos?
Vi que também está sendo introduzido um conceito novo que são as `sessions`. O que vem a ser uma `session`? Você pode incluir na resposta uma explanação sobre elas? Sei que parece ser um assunto para uma nova pergunta, mas pelo que percebi as `sessions` é o que fundamenta as transações no `pymongo` por isso acho pertinente.

Comment: Sim, são implícitos. Vou explicar um pouco sobre Sessions.

Comment: Mas você pode usar eles explicitamente, é o que aconteceu no segundo exemplo.